# HTMLAgilityPack: how to search for " .csv files " in the html

Tags: c#, browser, html-parsing

In my project , i need to download the csv files in the webpage . i am using HTmlAgility to extract html contents . and the html page following html code for .csv  file . The Portion of html which have link for csv files is ,

```
<td class="smalllinks" align="right">
<a href="/content/fo/contractvol/datafiles/OPTIDX_NIFTY_CE_31-08-2012_TO_31-08-2012.csv" target="_blank">Download file in csv format</a>
</td>
```

and what should be my xpath ?

```
 HtmlNodeCollection nodelist = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(_xpath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will get you the contents of all `HREF` attributes of all `A` elements on the page:

```
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a"))
{
    var aLink = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked but how to navigate to particular link using this ??  any example ??

Comment: @Vishwa - You need to learn XPath. You have not provided the structure of the HTML page, so it is impossible to suggest alternatives.